# ''.join() in ThreadPoolExecutor eat memory

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks

try code like this:

```
import gc
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

zen = "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. "


def abc(length: int):
    msg = ''.join(random.sample(zen, length))
    print(msg)
    del msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
    while True:
        for x in range(256):
            pool.submit(abc, random.randint(2, 6))
        print('===================================================')
        gc.collect()
```

The code may take about 8MB if it running without ThreadPoolExecutor, or about 30MB using str() instead of ''.join(). But this code keep eating RAM without limit. I thought it is caused by random.sample or something else, but it proved that ''.join() in ThreadPoolExecutor cause this problem.

It confuse me as there is no modules mutually import each other(share zen only), & neither the del or Gc work :(

ps: please notes that infinite loop is not a problem. when you run something like:

```
while True:
    print(1234567)
```

the memory usage will keeping under a certain line (code above may take not more than 1MB?). The code at the top don't have an increasing list or dict, & the variable has been del at the end of the module. So it should be cleaned up when a thread finish as I think, which obviously not.

pss: let's talk like this: the cause of the problem is anything in ''.join() will not be recycled. As if we change the abc module this way:

```
tmp = random.sample(zen, length)
msg = ''.join(tmp)
print(msg[:8])
del msg, tmp
```

Gc works effectively, and the usage keeping about 26MB.

## So is there something I missed when using ''.join() or python language has a bug there?

Comment: but you have an infinite loop here. Your program never ends. since you don't get the result of your `submit`, the pool grows and grows.

Comment: Your while loop never breaks. Obviously, it will keep growing.

Comment: sorry for didn't make it clear. When you run with a single thread, or without ''.join(), even with a infinite loop, the memory usage will keeping under a certain line, eg 8MB or more. It will not not not (important declare 3 times) grew to hundreds MB or even more(a similar example with 4096 threads eat up 13GB RAM). Only 'loop make it growing can't make sense to me bro.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code without threads each sentence will execute completely, and with that I mean that the `gc.collect()` will be called after the inner loop has ended.

But when you execute the code with threads a new thread will be called before the most recent one has ended, so the number of new threads will rapidly increase and as there's no limit for the number of threads you will have more threads than your CPU's can handle causing an accumulation of threads.